# Inquiry on different results of Mplus

Tags: r

I use Mplus to calculate LCGA. When using the same data and different machines to calculate, there may be a differential pressure in the results. Can someone help me solve this problem? The Mplus version used on different machines is the same

I have tried multiple machines and compared all the results. Some of the calculated results may or may not differ, and I look forward to someone answering

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.